# How to Share Files Between one computer with Windows 7 and another with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, file-sharing

How Can Share Files Between one computer with Windows 7 and another with Ubuntu?

What hardware do I need? I have only a wireless router... not sure where that gets me.

What steps do I need to take to setup each computer for file sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the computers are both on your own network then Windows file sharing using [`samba` on the Ubuntu machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/internet/C/networking-shares.html) *should* be the way to go, but for me, Windows 7 does not handle this very well and is *really* slow to pick up the other machines (Linux and XP which all interact properly).

Comment: Linux/Samba will work better as browse-master, as Windows 7 sometimes has troubles seeing the entire network.

Comment: I found a couple great guides that explain how to do it. It worked!!!

 Create a Windows Home Group: 
http://www.7tutorials.com/homegroup-feature-how-it-works

 Access Windows 7 Shared Folders from Ubuntu: 
http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-windows-7-shared-folders-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

you can consider setting up a FTP server. For ubuntu follow the tutorial [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/settingup-an-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-with-proftpd.html). Just connect the two computers to the same network and you can share the files through an ftp server. For syncing files over the internet you could consider using [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of DropBox, if the files are small this would work. The author of the question should specify more details about the files which are going to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 you can use NFS for file sharing.
Set up an NFS shared file system on your Ubuntu, and map it on Windows 7.

A look at the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/12414/how-do-you-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-7) site can help you getting started.